# Deadlock in dependent multiple update statements

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions

In a SP, three tables are getting updated in a single transaction. These update are dependent on each other. But intermittently deadlock is happening during this update. It is not happening consistently but rather intermittently.

A WCF service is being called and that calls the SP. The input of the SP is a XML. The XML is parsed wing the OPENXML method and the values are used to update the tables.

@Table is a table variable ,populated by OPENXML on applying the input XML of the SP. The input XML contains only one ID.

```
<A>
  <Value>XYZ</Value>
  <ID>1</ID>
</A>

BEGIN TRAN
--update Table1  
Update Table1
Set ColumnA = A.value
JOIN @Table A
ON Table1.ID = A.ID

--update Table2    
Update Table2
Set ColumnA = Table1.ColumnA
JOIN Table1
ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID

--update Table3
Update Table3
Set ColumnA = Table1.ColumnA
JOIN Table1
ON Table1.ID = Table3.ID

COMMIT TRAN
```

In Table1 , ID column is primary key.
In Table2, in ID column no index are available.

Here sometimes deadlock is happening while updating Table2.

Receiving the error "Transaction (Process ID 100) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction."

Advise is required on resolving this intermittent deadlock issue.

Comment: Is the `ID` column the primary key of all 3 tables? Check the execution plan to make sure only the single row is touched with a clustered index seek/update.

Comment: ID column is primary key in only Table1

Comment: Do you have an index on `ID` on the other tables. Is it the clustered index?

Comment: ID is clustered index in Table1 and Table3. However in Table2 there are no index on ID column.

Comment: The missing Table2 index is the likely cause. Try creating an index on `ID`, ideally clustered, so that only the rows to be updated are touched. Deadlocks are often a result of accessing more rows than needed and query/index tuning can mitigate the likelihood.

Comment: In Table2 already a clustered index is there. So, will it be beneficial to create non-clustered index on ID column in Table2 ?

Comment: Yes, I would expect a non-clustered index on `ID` will avoid touching rows you don't need. The execution plan will show if it's used.

Comment: After adding non-clustered index on the ID column of Table2, now it is showing noon-clustered index seek. Before it was showing clustered index scan.

Comment: I expect the better plan will reduce the deadlocks you were having.

Answer (score 0):

Deadlocks are often the result of more data being touched than needed by queries. Query and index tuning can help ensure only data needed by queries are accessed and locked, reducing both blocking and the likelihood of deadlocks by concurrent sessions.

Because your queries join on `ID` with no other criteria, an index on that column may help avoid the `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statements from touching other rows. I see from your comments that there was no index on the `table2` `ID` column so a clustered index scan was performed. Not only did the scan result in suboptimal performance, it can lead to blocking and deadlocking when concurrent sessions contend for the same rows.

Adding a non-clustered index on `ID` changed the plan from a full clustered index scan to a non-clustered index seek. This should reduce, if not eliminate, the deadlocks going forward and improve performance considerably too. I like to say that performance and concurrency go hand-in-hand, an especially important detail with data modification statements.

Comment: Currently we are using OPENXML to parse the input XML. If we replace it with  XML nodes(), then will it improve the performance of the overall query?

Comment: @ArunJoy, given the simple XML document, I wouldn't expect a significant difference using either method to load the table variable. If performance is important to you, don't take my word for it, [race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).